# Combining Formulas

Tags: 2013, datasheet

I need to combine the following formulas for SharePoint 2013. I've validated that each works separately, but when I try combining them I keep getting an error message.

Any suggestions:

```
=DATEDIF(Created,[Tech Pubs End Date],"d"

=([Tech Pubs End Date]="","0")

=IF(Created<[Tech Pubs End Date],"0")
```

Comment: All three of those formulas as stand alone formulas are incorrect/incomplete and ambiguous. Please edit your post with correct formulas then we'll be able to help. Also, if you could explain what you're trying to achieve, that would help too.

Answer (score 0):

Try below formula

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Tech Pubs End Date]), "0", IF([Created]<[Tech Pubs End Date], "0", DATEDIF([Created], [Tech Pubs End Date], "d")))
```